# Why I get data with not exist, if my 2 tables are the same? (Python,mysql)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to analogue 2 tables, these 2 tables are the same, but i get all data when i run my query. Why?

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='adam',
    passwd='',
    db='database1',
    use_unicode=True,
    charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ select `ACTUAL_TIME`, `ACTUAL_DAY`, `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`,     `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, `ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, `SCHEDULED_TIME`, `FLIGHT`, `FROM`, `AIRLANE`,`AIRCRAFT`, `STATUS`, `FLIGHT_ID_1`, `FLIGHT_ID_2`, `UPLOAD_TIME`
from OSSZES as a
where not exists(select `ACTUAL_TIME`, `ACTUAL_DAY`,`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`, `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, `ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, `SCHEDULED_TIME`, `FLIGHT`, `FROM`, `AIRLANE`,`AIRCRAFT`, `STATUS`, `FLIGHT_ID_1`, `FLIGHT_ID_2`, `UPLOAD_TIME`
from OSSZES_CLEAR as b
where `a`.`ACTUAL_DAY` = `b`.`ACTUAL_DAY` AND `a`.`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE` = `b`.`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE` AND `a`.`FLIGHT` = `b`.`FLIGHT` AND `a`.`SCHEDULED_TIME` = `b`.`SCHEDULED_TIME` AND `a`.`STATUS` = `b`.`STATUS`)
    into outfile '/tmp/proba.csv'
    fields terminated by ';'
    enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n';
    """
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you're trying to do. Assuming you want all records from table a where there is not a corresponding record in table b, and your logic in the subquery defines a proper join, here's how I'd do it.

```
    select 
      `ACTUAL_TIME`, 
      `ACTUAL_DAY`, 
      `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, 
      `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`,     
      `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, 
      `ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, 
      `SCHEDULED_TIME`, 
      `FLIGHT`, 
      `FROM`, 
      `AIRLANE`,
      `AIRCRAFT`, 
      `STATUS`, 
      `FLIGHT_ID_1`, 
      `FLIGHT_ID_2`, 
      `UPLOAD_TIME`
    from OSSZES as a
    left join (
      select 
        `ACTUAL_TIME`
        `ACTUAL_DAY`,
        COALESCE(`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`, '') as EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE -- edit
        `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_AIRPORT`, 
        `EXAMINED_AIRPORT_COUNTRY`, 
        `ARRIVALS/DEPARTURES`, 
        `SCHEDULED_TIME`, 
        `FLIGHT`, 
        `FROM`, 
        `AIRLANE`,
        `AIRCRAFT`, 
        `STATUS`, 
        `FLIGHT_ID_1`, 
        `FLIGHT_ID_2`, 
        `UPLOAD_TIME`
      from OSSZES_CLEAR
    ) as b using (`ACTUAL_DAY`,`EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE`,`FLIGHT`,`SCHEDULED_TIME`,`STATUS`)
    where b.EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE is null
    into outfile '/tmp/proba.csv'
    fields terminated by ';'
    enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n';
```

If that doesn't work, please clarify what result you're getting and what result you expect.

Comment: I get this error message:     mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'EXAMINED_AIRPORT_CODE' in 'from clause'")

Comment: That is straight from your supplied code, as far as I can see. Can you supply some information on table structure?

Comment: But what i posted it has worked.  Your code give this error message.

Comment: I've edited it so that the coalesce statement is aliased. Coalesce may be unnecessary, but since you haven't shared the structure of your data, I can't be sure.

Comment: ... what is the error message, and what is the structure of your tables? Please edit your question to include the structure of the tables. Please modify your source code to be a minimum reproducible example.
Here's the faq on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask